# Proper use of timer in windows service

Tags: c#, timer

I have following code to use timer (System.Timers.Timer) in *windows service*. The goal is that new time handler should not occur if previous one didn't finish its job. Here is how I achieve this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

            try
            {
                //
                // Create and start a timer.
                //
                m_mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                m_mainTimer.Interval = 60000;   // every one min
                m_mainTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
                m_mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
                m_mainTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              // omitted
            }

}
```

And:

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            // Service stopped. Also stop the timer.
            m_mainTimer.Enabled = false;
            m_mainTimer = null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

Also in handler:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
            }catch(Exceptione x)
            {
            }
            finally
            {

            if (null != m_mainTimer)
            {
                m_mainTimer.Start(); // re - enable the timer
            }
            }
}
```

It works but my question is is this approach safe? Maybe I should make `m_mainTimer` `volatile`? Because of the `null` check inside `finally`?

Comment: Are timer1 and m_mainTimer the same timer?

Comment: @TylerHarden: yes, I can't see timer1  actually

Comment: So every tick (60 seconds), you fire the timer1_Tick method, and then if the timer isn't null, start it again?

Comment: @Tyler Harden: yes but I am not sure if this way it is safe. Especially volatile what I mentioned

Answer (score 11):

Ok, had a few suggestions with the code for you to avoid some confusion and maintain some consistency. I'll start off with the code sample and add some comments after the code block:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private System.Timers.Timer m_mainTimer;
        private bool m_timerTaskSuccess;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //
                // Create and start a timer.
                //
                m_mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                m_mainTimer.Interval = 60000;   // every one min
                m_mainTimer.Elapsed += m_mainTimer_Elapsed;
                m_mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
                m_mainTimer.Start(); // Start

                m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // omitted
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                // Service stopped. Also stop the timer.
                m_mainTimer.Stop();
                m_mainTimer.Dispose();
                m_mainTimer = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // omitted
            }
        }

        void m_mainTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // do some work

                m_timerTaskSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (m_timerTaskSuccess)
                {
                    m_mainTimer.Start();
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**System.Windows.Forms.Timer versus System.Timers.Timer**

At one point in your code it is clear you dragged a Timer component into the design grid of the service, clicked it creating the Tick event, and then replaced with a `System.Timers.Timer` instead. I recommend sticking with either one or the other, and thus to maintain clarity I replaced your `timer1_Tick` event handler with `m_mainTimer_Elapsed`, since `System.Timers.Timer` utilize the **Elapsed** event instead of the **Tick** event.

**Use of a boolean success indicator**

Versus setting the timer to null when the Service is stopped, which at that point it is already too late to affect your running event, utilize a private boolean to hold whether success is achieved (dependent on how you define success in your project's domain). If an exception occurs during the running of the task, set it to false. Then utilize an if block to only restart the timer if the last run was successful.

**You do NOT need `volatile`**

You are only ever modifying the timer in one thread. `volatile` is utilized when multiple threads could potentially modify the same reference variable.

Comment: If service is stopped in the middle-timer set to null. Then finally executed I will get exception

Comment: You're not guaranteed for that to run in that order. You have no way to guarantee when the OnStop will call relative to where you are in the Elapsed event handler.

Comment: Yes but that is why i was checking against null in finally before calling method on the reference

Comment: So is the logic of my answer wrong, or? I just don't feel that using the timer reference as a method of determining whether to try to run the timer again really indicates the "success" of your operation. Sure if the timer is NOT null then you should run it again, but in your case the only time the timer is null is when the service is stopping, which inherently stops the timer anyways.

Comment: I am not catching up why bool flag is better than what I had. Plus like I said your approach will call method on null pointer if windows service was stopped when timer was running

Comment: Also you didn't mention if volatile is needed etc. But thanks for input. Maybe someone will post also other solution

Comment: The presence and utilization of my boolean flag is that it is set to true if your operation succeeds, false if an exception occurs, and starts off false when the service starts up.

Comment: Should it be volatile? And like i said in your version it may call method on null pointer. And if operation failed why not still restart the timer?

Comment: I updated my answer so we don't get carried away in the comments. You do not need volatile. And because in your original question you stated the whole point of the timer is that it should only restart and run again if it was successful last time, yet you had no indicator of success. "The goal is that new time handler should not occur if previous one didn't finish its job.". Maybe I am unclear on your wording here but that is how I interpreted it.

Comment: Yes Tyler indeed I don't care if opetation suceeded or not. I just meant it had to wait for previous handler method to return

Comment: Why does one has to dispose the timer on `Stop` ?
Because the process gets unloaded anyway milliseconds later..